# Adding Data to Arraylist to display in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

Please help. 
After developing an interface to communicate between fragments **"Calculator" (Sending Info)** and **"ShoppingList" (Receiving Info)** I can't seem to get the information to be added to my ArrayList. I know the information was sent over but I just can't seem to get it added to the list in order to incorporate it in my listview. 
Also, I should note. If I hardcode the information in 
eg: **myItems.add(new ListItems(R.drawable.thrash, "Cornflakes", 1, 50.00, 60.00));**
it works fine. I just want this process to be done dynamically.

Please Help.

Calculator.java

```
public class Calculator extends Fragment {


private static EditText ItemText, Editcost, Editquantity, Calcost, Rtax;
private static RadioGroup rgroup;

CalculatorListener activityCommander;


public interface CalculatorListener{
   public void addtoCart(String itemName, int qty, double beforeTax, double afterTax);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        activityCommander = (CalculatorListener) context;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
    }
}


public Calculator() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator, container, false);


    Editcost = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editcost);
    ItemText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
    Editquantity = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editquantity);
    Calcost = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.calcost);
    Rtax = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.rtax);

    rgroup = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.rgroup);

    final ImageButton FieldButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.FieldButton);
    final ImageButton TaxButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.TaxButton);
    final ImageButton CalButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.CalButton);

    Rtax.setEnabled(false);
    Calcost.setEnabled(false);

    ItemText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                              if (!hasFocus) {
                                                  v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittxt);
                                              } else {
                                                  v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittxtfocus);
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
    );

    Calcost.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                             if (hasFocus) {
                                                 v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittxtfocus);
                                             } else {
                                                 v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittxt);
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }
    );

    Editcost.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                              if (hasFocus) {
                                                  v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittxtfocus);
                                              } else {
                                                  v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittxt);
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
    );
    Editquantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                                  if (hasFocus) {
                                                      v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittxtfocus);
                                                  } else {
                                                      v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittxt);
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
    );



    CalButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    results(v);
                }

            }
    );

    return view;

}



public void results (View view)
{



    double taxValue = Double.parseDouble(Rtax.getText().toString()), cost = 0, newCost = 0;

    int quantity = 1, radiobuttonID = rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(), index;

    String item = ItemText.getText().toString();


    //FIELD VALIDATIONS
    if(Editcost.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        Toast show = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cost is required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        show.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        show.show();
    }


    //CHECKS THE TAX VALUE IF IT NEEDS TO BE CONVERTED
    if (taxValue > 1)
    {
        taxValue = taxValue / 100;
    }
    else
    {
        taxValue = taxValue * 1;
    }

    //CUSTOM VALIDATOR FOR QUANTITY FIELD
    if (Editquantity.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        quantity = 1;
    }
    else if (!Editquantity.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(Editquantity.getText().toString());
    }


    //DECIDE WHETHER TO USE TAX INCLUDED OR EXCLUDED
    View radioButton = rgroup.findViewById(radiobuttonID);
    index = rgroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);

    if(index == 0)
    {
        newCost = (((cost = Double.parseDouble(Editcost.getText().toString())) * taxValue) + cost) * quantity;
    }
    else if (index == 1)
    {
        newCost = ((cost = Double.parseDouble(Editcost.getText().toString())) * quantity);
    }


    //PRINTS NEW COST TO SCREEN
    Calcost.setText("" + newCost);


    //CUSTOM HINT POP UP
    if(!item.isEmpty())
    {
        Toast show = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item+" was added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        show.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        activityCommander.addtoCart(item, quantity, cost, newCost);
        show.show();

    }else if(item.isEmpty() & !Editcost.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        if (index == 0 || index == 1)
        {
            Toast show = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Item was added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            show.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            activityCommander.addtoCart(item, quantity, cost, newCost);
            show.show();
        }

    }



}
```

}

Core.java

```
public class Core extends AppCompatActivity implements Calculator.CalculatorListener{

Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.core);
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Calculator(),"Calculator");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ShoppingList(), "Shopping Cart");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}

@Override
public void addtoCart(String itemName, int qty, double beforeTax, double afterTax) {
    ShoppingList mShoppingList = (ShoppingList) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ShopFrag);
    if(mShoppingList != null)
    {
        mShoppingList.populatelist(itemName, qty, beforeTax, afterTax);
    }
    else{
        Log.e(Tag,"Cart is Null");
    }

}
```

ShoppingList.java

```
    package com.sta.salestaxaccumulator;


import android.app.LauncherActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ShoppingList extends Fragment {

    public List<ListItems> myItems = new ArrayList<ListItems>();



    public ShoppingList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopping_list, container, false);
        populatelistview(view);
        //setCart();
        return view;

    }


    public void populatelist(String itemName, int qty, double beforeTax, double afterTax)
    {


        myItems.add(new ListItems(R.drawable.thrash, itemName, qty, beforeTax, afterTax));
        //myItems.add(new ListItems(R.drawable.thrash, "Cornflakes", 1, 50.00, 60.00));

        /*Toast show = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),itemName+" is here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        show.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        show.show();*/
    }

    /*public void setCart(String itemName, int qty, double beforeTax, double afterTax)
    {
        //myItems.add(new ListItems(R.drawable.thrash, "Cornflakes", 1, 50.00, 60.00));
        //myItems.add(new ListItems(R.drawable.thrash, "Cheese", 1, 80.00, 90.00));
        //myItems.add(new ListItems(R.drawable.thrash, "Rice", 1, 40.00, 70.00));
        //myItems.add(new ListItems(R.drawable.thrash, "Oatmeal", 2, 35.00, 62.00));
    }*/


    public void populatelistview(View view)
    {
        ArrayAdapter<ListItems> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItems>
    {
        public MyListAdapter()
        {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_row, myItems);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Ensures we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
            }

            //Finds the item to work with
            ListItems currentitem = myItems.get(position);

            //Fills the view
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Thrash);
            imageView.setImageResource(currentitem.getIconID());

            //Item Name
            TextView name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ItemName);
            name.setText(currentitem.getItemName());

            //Item Qty
            TextView qty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.QuantityValue);
            qty.setText("" + currentitem.getQty());

            //Before Tax
            TextView btax = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.BeforeTaxValue);
            btax.setText("" + currentitem.getBeforeTax());

            //After Tax
            TextView atax = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.AfterTaxValue);
            atax.setText("" + currentitem.getAfterTax());


            imageView.setTag(currentitem);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myItems.remove(myItems.get(position));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            });

            return itemView;
        }

    }



}
```

ListItems.java

```
    package com.sta.salestaxaccumulator;


public class ListItems {
    private int IconID;
    private String ItemName;
    private int Qty;
    private double BeforeTax, AfterTax;

    public ListItems(int iconID, String itemName, int qty, double beforeTax, double afterTax) {
        IconID = iconID;
        ItemName = itemName;
        Qty = qty;
        BeforeTax = beforeTax;
        AfterTax = afterTax;
    }

    public int getIconID() {
        return IconID;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return ItemName;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return Qty;
    }

    public double getBeforeTax() {
        return BeforeTax;
    }

    public double getAfterTax() {
        return AfterTax;
    }

}
```

Core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http//schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tools2="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sta.salestaxaccumulator.Core">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/AppBarFrag">

        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/AppBarFrag">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.sta.salestaxaccumulator.Calculator"
            tools2:layout="@layout/fragment_calculator"
            android:id="@+id/CalcuFrag" />

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.sta.salestaxaccumulator.ShoppingList"
            tools2:layout="@layout/fragment_shopping_list"
            android:id="@+id/ShopFrag"/>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>




</RelativeLayout>
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{


    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragments, String titles)
    {
        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);

    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this help, try adapter.notifydatasetchanged() when you put some new data into your array, this will refresh the listView

Comment: In my populatelistview(View view) method I added adapter.notifydatasetchanged() at the end and nothing changed. The listview still came back empty.

Comment: sometimes this is due to the xml file try with just some textView

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if information is sent over, by logging details which are passed in the method. If there is a positive response call for **notifyDataSetChanged();**
It will notify the listview about new item being added to list.

Please comment below if it is working or not by trying the above. If not we can get it fixed.

Comment: In my populatelistview(View view) method I added adapter.notifydatasetchanged() at the end and nothing changed. The listview still came back empty.

Comment: Yes. You may not be getting any data. So firstly check if you are getting information in populatelist() method which you are passing through listener.

Comment: I am getting data in the populatelist() method. I tested that with a toast.

Comment: Then i guess something is wrong in adapter. Check your adapter once if values are being received correctly.

Comment: sigh, i guess. Idk if i'm asking to much here but could you write an adapter that takes my user input that's passed in the ShoppingList fragment and add it to a listview. It would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after `myItem.add()` in `populatelist()`. For that, make the adapter defined in `populatelistview()` a global and then you could try calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` (something similar to what you have done in `getView()`:

```
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myItems.remove(myItems.get(position));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Made the adapter into a global variable and tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() but the listview still doesn't populate.